# react native bind this undefined function

Tags: javascript, react-native, socket.io

I am trying to set state after socket on function but

```
componentWillMount() {
socket.on('foo', function(msg){
//alert(JSON.stringify(msg));
//this.setState({user:msg});
this.setState({veri:msg});
this.setState({initial:msg});

});
```

> undefined is not a function (evaluating 'this.setState({ veri: msg
>   })') 
>       index.android.js:95:14 emit
>       index.js:133:25 onevent
>       socket.js:270:15 onpacket
>       socket.js:228:19 
>       index.js:21:20 emit
>       index.js:133:25 ondecoded
>       manager.js:345:12 
>       index.js:21:20 emit
>       index.js:133:25 add
>       index.js:241:16 ondata
>       manager.js:335:19 
>       index.js:21:20 emit
>       index.js:133:25 onPacket
>       socket.js:457:18 
>       socket.js:274:18 emit
>       index.js:133:25 onPacket
>       transport.js:145:12 onData
>       transport.js:137:16 onmessage
>       websocket.js:147:16 dispatchEvent
>       event-target.js:172:43 
>       WebSocket.js:148:27 emit
>       EventEmitter.js:182:12
>   __callFunction
>       MessageQueue.js:250:47 
>       MessageQueue.js:101:26
>   __guard
>       MessageQueue.js:218:6 callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
>       MessageQueue.js:100:17

Comment: What is `this`?

Comment: this is react native

Comment: He means, there isn't enough code visible to properly determine what `this` is. You may think it's supposed to be React Native or something, but since `setState` is undefined, `this` isn't what you think it is.

Comment: Yes, of course. I mean the `this` object in your code snippet.

Comment: if you familiar with rn .....

Comment: If you're familiar with JavaScript.... `this` has many different meaning based on the context it is used. `this` doesn't always refer to the top-level element you're in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's not possible to tell conclusively from the small chunk of code you provided, it's likely that `this` inside of `socket.on` is referring to the socket, not React.

You could either try using an arrow function:

```
socket.on('foo', msg => {
    this.setState({veri:msg});
    this.setState({initial:msg});
});
```

You could also set `this` to something (like `self`) before calling `socket`, then use `self` instead of `this` inside:

```
const self = this;
socket.on('foo', function(msg){
    this.setState({veri:msg});
    this.setState({initial:msg});
});
```

You could also define the function outside the handler, and bind it to `this`:

```
const handleFoo = (function(msg){
    this.setState({veri:msg});
    this.setState({initial:msg});
}).bind(this);

socket.on('foo', handleFoo);
```

All three of those are ways to keep `this` what you expect and not let it change inside of another context.